alternatives to a bridged wlan connection for a libvirt host
I need a qemu vm to have a stand alone private ip on my lan.  I only have a wifi physical device.  NAT mode won't work as I need the guest to have it's own ARP table.
I'm seeing non-unique MACs on my wifi network and need to investigate.  I've locked down my host ARP table to the known good MAC address.  I want a vm to use the suspect MAC so I can investigate.  I don't think I'm willing to expose my host to this device without better understanding what's going on here.  The device in question is a NetGear Network extender, so it raises some red flags to me.
Is there anyway to get unique lan ips(perferably through router's DHCP) for my vms AND my host all with unique MACs such that I can manipulate requests at the ARP level?
I'm running fedora 41 and libvirt.

Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices and hosts/servers/VMs are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].
